# Dynamic task name in ant: is it possible?

Tags: dynamic, ant

In my ant project there are situations where I invoke move or copy tasks depending on the conditions with exactly same parameters (and enclosed mappers/filesets). I would like to put that into parameterised code. Of course this way does not work:

```
<if ...>
<then><property name="operation" value="move"></then>
<else><property name="operation" value="copy"></else>
</if>

<${operation} ...
```

Any way to implement it?